# Difficulty in hint display for edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Hi i used hint for edit text 
it shows perfect when i was not used `gravity` of edit text as *center*

but once when i used `android:gravity="center"` it doesnot showing hint 
anyone know why?

here is my code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <include layout="@layout/header" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/maroon"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_rllogin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="gone" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_et_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint_enterpassword"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/dark_gray" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_btn_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_et_password"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_et_password"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_et_password"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/fent_orange"
                android:text="@string/login_btn_caption"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/login_rlreg"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:visibility="visible" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_et_repassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint_reenterpassword"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/dark_gray" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/login_btn_submit"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/login_et_repassword"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_et_repassword"
                android:layout_below="@+id/login_et_repassword"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/fent_orange"
                android:text="@string/submit_btn_caption"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/login_et_choosepassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/login_et_repassword"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="@string/login_hint_choosepassword"
                android:inputType="numberPassword"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textColorHint="@color/dark_gray" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAppTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/login_rlreg"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:background="@color/white" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ztam"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="7dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/login_rlreg"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:background="@color/fent_orange"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post whole xml layout or screenshot?

Comment: Why do you need to use gravity="center"?

Comment: cause i want that inputed data in center/hint in center its my requirment

Comment: can u see your hint in xml layout ?

Comment: android:visibility="gone" ?

Comment: I wrote your code and it is showing the hint in center?

Comment: @Amrut yes i can see in xml design layout but not in
actual device

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal there are 2 layout one for login and one for registration
dont focus on it it works gud only problem is hint

Comment: @VikrantAlekar what are the operaions you're performing on your editText . please post your whole java code.

Comment: @Amrut
just doing normal input nothing else
i think java code not necessary to show it just basic xml related problem

Comment: @SirSC  my device is android 2.3.6 samsung galaxy s advance 

is it compatibility issue??

Comment: @VikrantAlekar i dnt 9 whats u doing wrong bcz on my system with change color it works fine so will u change color once . No issue on my system

Comment: @VikrantAlekar yes it's working fine on my system